# Convert part non-numeric string to double

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to convert a string to double, that also contains non numeric characters. I was wondering if there's a general solution to this, instead of find the index of every non-numeric character in the string and remove them one by one. (Something like atof())

For example, here is my string line (2 vectors coordinates):

"[12,75082301   28,53644171 119,392771]     [108,4213282    30,04183776 77,14237388]"
(separated by \t and doublequotes are included inside string)

I splitted tindo an string array

```
array<String^> ^columns;
columns = line->Split('\t');
```

And in my first column there's: *"[12,75082301*

And in my third column there's: *119,392771]*

Is there a simple way to convert thoose string into double with the same method?

(And follow up question: if there's 2 '\t' directli next to each other, with the StringSplitOption::RemoveEmptyEntries I should be able to skip empty entry, but It seems not to work for me...any idea?)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You're just talking about removing the square brackets, right?  The commas look like they're meant to be fraction separators.  (I mention this because English-speaking countries use a period, and not everyone is aware that many other cultures use a comma.)

Comment: Oh yes sorry I forgot. Commas are indeed separators!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "non-numeric" characters can appear anywhere in the string (i.e. in the middle of your number "1,123[456") then you can't escape preprocessing the string and removing them. Luckily, you can do this in one pass using `std::remove_if` of `std::copy_if` algorithms.

However, if your "non-numeric" characters only appear either at the beginning or at the end of your string, you can actually treat them as whitespaces and "split" your string correctly using a `stringstream` with a customized locale. Define a facet that will treat `[`, `]`, and `\t` as spaces and you're good to go. Doing this will also take care of your second issue - several adjacent `\t` characters.

In addition to this you can define another facet that will treat `,` as a decimal point. Combine it with the previous one and you can read `double`s directly from your original string.

Here's the code that does all this. First, facets:

```
struct custom_space_facet: std::ctype<char> {
    custom_space_facet(const std::string& s): std::ctype<char>(get_table(s)) {}

    static const std::ctype_base::mask* get_table(std::string const &s) {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());
        for (auto ch : s) rc[ch] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

struct decimal_coma_facet : std::numpunct<char> {
    char do_decimal_point() const { return ','; }
};
```

Next, the code itself:

```
auto l1 = std::locale(std::locale(), new custom_space_facet(" \t[]"));
auto l2 = std::locale(std::locale(), new decimal_coma_facet);

auto locale = l1.combine<std::numpunct<char>>(l2);

std::stringstream input("[12,75082301 28,53644171   119,392771] [108,4213282 30,04183776 77,14237388]");
input.imbue(locale);

std::cout << std::setprecision(10);

double value;
while (input >> value)
   std::cout << value << "\n";
```

Running this will give you the desired doubles:

```
12.75082301
28.53644171
119.392771
108.4213282
30.04183776
77.14237388
```